# If $h(x)=f(g(x))$ is a composite function, what are the simple choices of $f$ and $g$ if $h(x)=\sqrt{\sin x}$, $h(x)=\sin \sqrt{x}$ or $h(x)=(x-1)^6$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $h(x)=f(g(x))$ is a composite function. I want to find simple choices of $f$ and $g$ if $h(x)=\sqrt{\sin x},\;\;h(x)=\sin \sqrt{x}$ and $h(x)=(x-1)^6$. Can anyone help me check if it's correct?

Here is what I've done:

1. $h(x)=\sqrt{\sin x}$, where $g(x)=\sin x$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{g(x)}$.
2. $h(x)=\sin \sqrt{x}$, where $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $f(x)=\sin g(x)$.
3. $h(x)=(x-1)^6$, where $g(x)=x-1$ and $f(x)= g(x)^6$.

Thanks to SxS: for the correction! So, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}, \;\;\sin (x)$ and $x^6$, instead! Thanks all!

Comment: Simpler than $f(x) = \sqrt x, g(x)= \sin x$ in the first case? And how is this related to [limits] or [continuity]?

Comment: @ Martin R: I'll change that, right away!

Comment: Your question is still unclear to me. There are “obvious” choices for $f$ and $g$ in all three cases, what do you consider a “simple” choice? And why [step-function]?

Comment: You literally wrote the simple choices. To list them in no particular order: $\sin x, \sqrt{x}, x-1, x^6.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when $$h(x) = \sqrt\sin x $$

$f(x) = \sqrt x$ and $g(x) = \sin x$

When $$h(x) = \sin{\sqrt\, x}$$

$f(x) = \sin x$  and $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$

Finally, when $$h(x) = (x-1)^6$$

$f(x) = x^6$ and $g(x) = x-1$